# Gesture and Grid itemonclick issue

Tags: android, gridview, gesture, android-gesture

I have implemented Gesture and GridView with setOnItemClickListener. I am using the same method given [from this website](http://misha.beshkin.lv/android-swipe-gesture-implementation/).

Now the problem is I want to use Gesture and on gridView as well as setonItemclicklistener too.

I am not able to use both. If I disable gesture for gridView items click works. If I enable gesture for gridView itemClick doesn't work.

Can somebody give me good solution to have both gesture and ItemClick?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem that inside Grid onClick worked fine but not gestures.
Overrriding dispatchTouchEvent helped.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (mDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    mDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```